# Travis CI job failing with unknown result "configured"

Tags: node.js, travis-ci

Here is my `.travis.yml`

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 0.8
before_script:
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
  - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
```

Simply getting:

```
Using worker: worker-linux-2-1.bb.travis-ci.org:travis-linux-19
An error occured while compiling the build script : unknown result "configured"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem here for my project ([see](https://travis-ci.org/lviggiano/owner/builds/12074089))

I think it's some sort of maintenance problem in travis build servers.

I don't think we can fix our travis configuration.

Comment: Other jobs on travis seem to be working. Maybe just a problem with `node.js`.

Comment: Other jobs are failing too with same error. This morning some of my build started to work again, and I did not change anything on my project that is affecting travis. It's not a problem affecting only `node.js` since my project is `Java` based and suffers the same issue.

Comment: Sorry, that one was on us (Travis CI). We deployed a mitigation for problems reaching the GitHub API, and this fix was faulty, but fixed later. Please let us know (support@travis-ci.com) if you're still seeing this issue on new commits.